# Why DD4T JMSTransportListener implementation has hard binding with Apache ActiveMQ

Tags: 2013-sp1, cache, dd4t-java, jms

To enable JMS cache invalidation in a dd4t-2.0 webapp, we need to add below bean in the Spring configuration of webapp. For Details check [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/16977/enable-dd4t-cache-and-tridion-cache-channel-service-when-using-dd4t-2-0-5-java/16978#16978)

```
<bean id="jmsTransportListener" 
  class="org.dd4t.core.caching.jms.impl.JMSTransportListener"/>
```

Now `JMSTransportListener` class does import **org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportListener**

```
package org.dd4t.core.caching.jms.impl;    
import org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportListener;    
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JMSTransportListener implements TransportListener {
...
.....
}
```

This creates issues when we are using any other JMS server and not ActiveMQ it throws Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportListener

Error Logs below:

```
WARN AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext:546 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myproject.testapp.web.interceptor.CommonRequestAttributesInterceptor com.myproject.testapp.web.config.WebConfig.commonRequestAttributesInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.dd4t.core.caching.jms.impl.JMSTransportListener] for bean with name 'jmsTransportListener' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportListener
ERROR ContextLoader:353 - Context initialization failed
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myproject.testapp.web.interceptor.CommonRequestAttributesInterceptor com.myproject.testapp.web.config.WebConfig.commonRequestAttributesInterceptor; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.dd4t.core.caching.jms.impl.JMSTransportListener] for bean with name 'jmsTransportListener' defined in class path resource [dispatcher-servlet.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/activemq/transport/TransportListener
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
```

Is there any clean way to fix this issue rather than adding ActiveMQ dependency in the `pom.xml` because I do not want to use any references of ActiveMQ if that is not part of project implementation. Any thoughts on same are most welcomed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no generic Transport Listener specification in the JMS Api / specification, so hence it's not possible to keep this part generic.

You should be able simply remove the transportListener and the references to it and then invalidation will still work.

Comment: Hi Raimond; thanks for the comment; can you please share some comments to have the ConnectionFactory working which is part of this same configuration. Separate post created for this https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17242/how-to-configure-jms-connectionfactory-in-dd4t2-0-java-webapp-when-its-osb-as-jm

Answer (score 1):

I guess the conclusion maybe is that the name of the class `JMSTransportListener` should possibly have been `ActiveMQTransportListener` instead, and if you are not intenting to use ActiveMQ, you should implement your own `jmsTransportListener`.

However I'm not completely sure because you fail to mention what changes you are making to support your other JMS server. Note the `org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportListener` is just an interface, if that is a universal JMS Transport Listener interface (I don't know), including the ActiveMQ dependency in the `pom.xml` would be considered acceptable. But again, you failed to supply the details in your question for me to make this conclusion (maybe you can edit your question and supply a bit more detail about that).

Comment: Hi Bart; I was expecting DD4T2.0-Java to be generic and support JMS Cache Invalidation with any JMS server used. And allows this by using relevant conf/class names in the bean entries as per the JMS server used. Is there any configuration available that can work for JMS server like OSB.

Comment: @GulshanThakur I don't know actually, the one thing I do know is that technically the JMS messages are not an open API, so while it is very nice and the most useful cache invalidation, it is also a bit of a hack. So I'm guessing you have some work to do yourself, good thing it's open source.

Answer (score 0):

After skipping the reference for JMSTransportListener it works and complete working configuration is present in below post

[How to configure JMS ConnectionFactory in DD4T2.0-Java webapp when its OSB as JMS server](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17242/how-to-configure-jms-connectionfactory-in-dd4t2-0-java-webapp-when-its-osb-as-jm/17270#17270)